# Angular 2 check element visibility

Tags: angular, components, element, visibility

How can I check if an element (or a component) is visible on the screen?

In a specific case, I have a component inside a bootstrap dropdown, and I want my component to do someting only if the dropdown is open (but I don't want to use a reference to the dropdown item).

Answer (score 0):

I would make use of ng-bootstrap if you're not already, and specifically the NgbDropdown component.

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown

It has an openChange event that fires when the menu opens or closes, and you can listen for that event and fire your own logic.

It also has an isOpen Method that you can check to see if the menu is open or not.

If those options don't do the trick, you can disable the dropdown button itself, and create your own button to toggle the dropdown and make use of manual triggers to open the menu and start your custom logic, and stop your logic and close the menu, although be careful of making a standard-looking interface element behave in a weird way as that will confuse users.